# CLI version of ubuntu14.0.4 to full graphics version of ubuntu14.0.4

Tags: upgrade

[image]I have an old desktop(2010) which has certain limitations - no boot possible from USB or DVD...so i need to go with mini.iso of ubuntu 14.0.4 and then installed ubuntu along side Windows 10. This desktop has 7 GB of RAM, dual core processor(AMD Athlon X2), 256 MB Graphics card and around 1.7 TB of hard drive...overall good configuration to run Ubuntu into Xwindows mode(default Ubuntu Desktop). How i can upgrade to the Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 or Ubuntu Desktop 15.x? What i am seeing is a very basic CLI kind of interface after using this mini.iso....Moreover my keyboard is not fully mapped it seems...how to fix that?

Bottomline i need to get into the XWindows mode(default ubuntu Desktop) and then use this as a regular Ubuntu Desktop system. CLI is very limited according to me.

Found some other issues with mini.iso installation - because it's more like a command line installation....good amount of manual stuff(selection of packages etc... required on my side)...Keyboard layout was wrongly set..and some other issues.
I am talking about mini.iso which has Ubuntu Desktop 64 bit image. Desktop should have the XWindows kind of interface rather than just CLI.

Comment: Which Ubuntu flavour did you install? Was it a "server" release (no GUI by default) or one of the desktop releases (with GUI by default)?

Comment: Desktop. But finally i am able to overcome this issue...now i have a working Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4 with Unity and that's what i wanted.

Comment: To voters: please re-open this question. OP has issues running the graphical user interface on *Ubuntu Desktop* not on Ubuntu Server. Considering their last comment, we should then close the question as off topic because it's now irreproducable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eduardo Cola for your response. 
I re-run the mini.iso installation in rescue mode(all the steps in the same way and this time i choose to pick up the Keyboard layout as US-EN...to fix my keyboard and this time selected the right packages... apart from ubuntu-desktop - i need to get the basic essential packages also....had some trouble with the GNome Desktop and finally switched to unity Desktop. All issues seems to be resolved. I had a very constraint desktop but finally able to overcome all the issues...has a working Ubuntu Desktop now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

Just run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and wait for the installation. Shouldn't take very long.